# Can we run Junit5 cases in eclipse mars?

Tags: eclipse-mars, junit5

- Shall we run Junit5 with eclipse-mars
- Below are the jars added into build path

[image]

Comment: JUnit 5 support requires Eclipse Oxygen see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php)